# How do i import email addresses into WordPress.com subscriptions?

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I have a CSV file with email addresses i want to import into Wordpress.coms Jetpack subscriptions.

Comment: And your research effort is …?

Comment: Not possible based on my research. If they are stored in the database then i should be able to import them but its too technical for me so i need help with this one. Curious to see if anybody has done this.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress.com Jetpack subscriptions are not hosted on your site, they're hosted on the WordPress.com servers.  So you can't add directly to the database.

However, if you take a look at the Jetpack plugin code, it outlines the XML-RPC calls used to interface with WordPress.com and add subscribers.  So you could build your own importer ...

```
// Some kind of function that parses your CSV file into an array of email addresses
$subscribers = get_subscribers_from_csv(); 

foreach( $subscribers as $email) {
    Jetpack_Subscriptions::subscribe( $email );
}
```

Comment: Is that it? Will this code work?

Comment: @braddalton Test it. Sooner or later you have to get your own hands dirty.

Comment: Happy too but not sure how WordPress.com would react! Cannot test Jetpack locally

Comment: Here is the code: https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/modules/subscriptions.php#L445